# mysql: permission error starting a server

Tags: mysql

I installed mysql community server on my macbook.  A password for the user "root@localhost" was created.  I have this saved.  When I tried to create a connection in mysql admin I noticed that the "default" user was "loisgh".  When I try to start the connection using the generated password I get an error that the password is incorrect.

Please advise on how I can create a password for user loisgh OR login as root.  I don't see a place where I can enter a user ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to connect mysql server:

```
mysql -uroot -p yourpwd
```

After successful  connect to server , to delete the account "loisgh"